# C# Globals/Constants bindable to DDLs, but with "Nice" names

Tags: c#, enums, constants, global

For the usual reasons, I need to use some constants in my application.

The approaches I've considered:

1) Declare an Enum:

```
public enum myOptions
{
  MyOption1 = 72,
  MyOption2 = 31,
  MyOption3 = 44
}
```

While this is good to program against, and I can bind the enum directly to a DDL, but the Enum "names" are ugly when the user sees them - The user will see "MyOption1" and I want them to see "My Option #1".

2) Use a List:

```
public static List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> myOptions = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>
{
 new KeyValuePair<int, string>(77, "My Option #1"),
 new KeyValuePair<int, string>(31, "My Option #2"),
 new KeyValuePair<int, string>(44, "My Option #3")
}
```

So while this binds very nicely to a DDL, gives me a nice display value as well as an integer return value, I don't have anything to test my return value against. So, for example:

```
if (selectedOption=????) //I'd have to hardcode the Key or Value I want to test for.
```

3) I could build nice Global/Constants assembly:

```
static myOptions
{
 public static KeyValuePair<int, string> MyOption1 = new new KeyValuePair<int, string>(77, "My Option #1");
 public static KeyValuePair<int, string> MyOption2 = new new KeyValuePair<int, string>(31, "My Option #2");
 public static KeyValuePair<int, string> MyOption3 = new new KeyValuePair<int, string>(44, "My Option #3");
}
```

Which gives me nice display names, is nice to code against, but as far as I can tell there's no way for me to easily bind this to a DDL (I'd have to hand code it).

Does anyone have an elegant way of creating constants that are easily bound against a DDL, where I can have a nice display name?

Right now the only thing I can think of is building BOTH the Enum and the List, which seems annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always lean toward decorated enum values:

```
public enum myOptions
{
    [Description("My Option #1")]
    MyOption1 = 72,
    [Description("My Option #2")]
    MyOption2 = 31,
    [Description("My Option #3")]
    MyOption3 = 44
}
```

or better yet you could create a custom attribute that would bind to a Resource file or a configuration setting so this data could be changed without recompiling

```
public enum myOptions
{
    [Custom("MyOption1Key")]
    MyOption1 = 72,
    [Custom("MyOption2Key")]
    MyOption2 = 31,
    [Custom("MyOption3Key")]
    MyOption3 = 44
}
```

---

Update to generically pull attributes from an enum

```
public static T GetAttribute<T>(this Enum e) where T : Attribute
{
    FieldInfo fieldInfo = e.GetType().GetField(e.ToString());
    T[] attribs = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false) as T[];
    return attribs.Length > 0 ? attribs[0] : null;
}
```

Comment: How do you suggest I bind the decorated enum to the DDL?

Comment: extract the attribute from the enum

Comment: I'm under the impression that I'll have to  loop through the enum pulling out each description. Is there a way bind it directly?

I'm hoping there is something similar to what I can to with the list of key-value-pairs, where I just set ddl.DataSource = new BindingSource(myKVPList, null);

Comment: Sorry - just noticed the update with your proposed extraction method. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Be careful with Reflection... if used improperly, it can be **very** slow.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer provided by @hunter, I decided to post my full implementation since it took me a while to get it right (still learning here...)

```
// This is the class I used to hold the extensions.
public static class EnumFunctions
{
    // Custom GetAttribute Extension - used to pull an attribute out of the enumerations.
    // This code is as per Hunter's answer, except I added the null check.
    public static T GetAttribute<T>(this Enum e) where T : Attribute
    {
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = e.GetType().GetField(e.ToString());

        // If the enumeration is set to an illegal value (for example 0,
        // when you don't have a 0 in your enum) then the field comes back null.
        // test and avoid the exception.
        if (fieldInfo != null)
        {
            T[] attribs = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false) as T[];
            return attribs.Length > 0 ? attribs[0] : null;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Custom GetKeyValuePairs - returns a List of <int,string> key value pairs with
    // each Enum value along with it's Description attribute.
    // This will only work with a decorated Enum. I've not included or tested what
    // happens if your enum doesn't have Description attributes.
    public static List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> GetKeyValuePairs(this Enum e)
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> ret = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();

        foreach (Enum val in Enum.GetValues(e.GetType()))
        {
            ret.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(Convert.ToInt32(val), val.GetAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>().Description));
        }
        return ret;
    }

}
```

Elsewhere, to do the binding to a DDL you can simply do this:

```
{
    // We need an instance of the enum to call our extension method.
    myOptions o = myOptions.MyOption1;

    // Clear the combobox
    comboBox1.DataSource = null;
    comboBox1.Items.Clear();

    // Bind the combobox
    comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(o.GetKeyValuePairs(), null);
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "Key";      
}
```

Finally, to pull the selected value out you can do this:

```
{
    // Get the selected item in the combobox
    KeyValuePair<int, string> selectedPair = (KeyValuePair<int, string>)comboBox1.SelectedItem;

    //I'm just sticking the values into text labels to demonstrate.
    lblSelectedKey.Text = selectedPair.Key.ToString();
    lblSelectedValue.Text = selectedPair.Value.ToString();
}
```

..and I didn't stop there. I extended the ComboBox control itself, so binding it now is super-convenient.

```
    // Extends the Combobox control so that it can be automatically bound to an Enum
    // that has been decorated with Description attributes.
    // Sets the current value of the combobox to the value of the enum instance passed in.
    public static void BindToDecoratedEnum(this System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox cb, Enum e)
    {
        // Clear the combobox
        cb.DataSource = null;
        cb.Items.Clear();

        // Bind the combobox
        cb.DataSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(e.GetKeyValuePairs(), null);
        cb.DisplayMember = "Value";
        cb.ValueMember = "Key";

        cb.Text = e.GetAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>().Description;
    }
```

So now, whenever I want to populate a DDL, I just:

```
        myDDL.BindToDecoratedEnum(myEnumInstanceWithValue);
```

The code binds it, and selected the item that matches the current value of the Enum passed in.

Comments and criticism on my implementation is welcome (actually, I'd be thankful - like I said, I'm trying to learn...)

Comment: +1 nice, I'm sure you could refactor here and there but overall not bad

Answer (score 1):

Another Suggestion?

```
public static List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> GetKeyValuePairs<T>()
    {
        Type enumType = typeof(T);

        List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> ret = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
        foreach (Enum val in Enum.GetValues(enumType))
        {
            ret.Add(
                new KeyValuePair<int, string>(Convert.ToInt32(val),
                val.GetAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>().Description)
                );
        } return ret;
    }
```

Then you can bind without having to create an instance of the enum. It is the type of enum you want information about, not a specific instance)

```
ddlPes.DataSource = EnumHelper.GetKeyValuePairs<PesId>();
ddlPes.DataValueField = "key";
ddlPes.DataTextField = "value";
ddlPes.DataBind();
```